# How to pass Kerberos token from spring-data-mongodb to kerborized mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, kerberos, spring-data-mongodb, spring-boot-actuator

I've a kerberozied MongoDB and I can connect to it using native java/scala clients using its kerberos implementation. However I'm not finding relevant information to achieve the same using spring-data-mongodb.

I found this link http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-kerberos/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/ which talks about spring security kerberos implementation, but its not related to spring-boot-mongodb.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and helpful pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Config just set up the `MongoClient` with the required `MongoClientURI` or `MongoCredential` for GSSAPI. In case you prefer XML config there's a dedicated `client-uri` as well.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
class Config extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "database";
  }

  @Override
  public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient(
      new MongoClientURI("mongodb://username%40REALM.com@host1/?authMechanism=GSSAPI"));
  }
}
```